# In Cakephp, how to prevent sql injection if I use direct mysql queires rather than using models?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pdo

I have to deal with large mysql DB. Sql queries with lot of calculations (in select clause) and several kind of conditions in where clauses. So, I decided to use row/direct sql queries to deal with DB by using `$db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');`

If I use this, how I prevent sql injection in mysql query? "mysql_real_escape_string" no longer exists. Is there any way to use PDO within CakePHP?

Comment: Why do you want to bypass using CakePHP's method of querying the database? Is there something in particular you can't do? One of the main benefits of using a framework like Cake is that you don't need to worry about SQL injections as the framework already handles this for you!

Comment: There are mathematical calculations has to be in 'select' queries, which cakephp find() can not implement. * - I am not sure whether it is possible, it gave me errors one after the other. And if I use 'model',  system taking too long time to load or sometimes goes memory exhaust issue. But if I use row sql, quickly respond. There are millions of data in the tables.

Comment: `find()` should work fine with calculations. You can use SQL methods in your select queries. Which version of CakePHP are you using? Perhaps you should be asking how to use calculations in your CakePHP queries rather than how to prevent SQL injections by bypassing the protections Cake has already in place!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this in your controller (or component)

```
// Initiate PDO connection
$this->_pdocon = $this->WhateverYourModel->getDataSource()->getConnection();
try {

    // Select Query
    $company = "What";
    $stmt = $this->_pdocon->prepare('SELECT * FROM `agents` WHERE `company` LIKE :company LIMIT 2');
    $stmt->bindValue(':company', $company, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    // Start transaction
    $this->_pdocon->begin();

    // Loop through the events
    if( $stm->execute() ) {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $stmt2 = $this->_pdocon->prepare("INSERT INTO `company` 
                        (`id`, `name`, `identityno`, `modified`, `created`) 
                        VALUES 
                        (NULL, :name, :identityno, NOW(), NOW())");
            $stmt2->bindValue(':name', $row['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt2->bindValue(':identityno', $row['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt2->execute();

        }
    }

    // Commit transaction
    $this->_pdocon->commit();

    // Get last insert Id
    $row_id = $this->_pdocon->lastInsertId();
    var_dump($row_id); 

} catch (PDOException $e) {

    // Rollback transaction
    $this->_pdocon->rollback();

    echo "! PDO Error : " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
}
```

This is what I ended-up. Using PDO has been solved thousands of issues. Now the system is fast and no memory exhaust error. And I can not putting all issues, errors what I got, in my question. It's good to giving direct answer rather trying to changing questions in here!

Answer (score 1):

A large part of the point of cakePhp is not to do this. Therefore I would recommend not doing this.

Cakephp has a its own implementation for accessing a DB and you should use it if at all possible. Is there a particular reason you want to go around it?

if you realy want to, you can still use mysqli but I cant recommend it.